How to print the processed argument after each command invocation with xargs
i run this command:
ls -1 | xargs -I% -n1 -P8 myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o %.dat %

it works with 8 runs at one time, the -q switch in myprogramm for quit, that is ok so.
but i will add something like this ; echo % to become the output name at the screen if the programm run is finished, for each run.
i run this command:
ls -1 | xargs -I% -n1 -P8 myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o %.dat % ; echo %

i see no errors, but the output is not that what i wanted.
i see after all runs are finished in bash only a new line with only one sign, %
but i will have the output like:
file1
file2
file3
...

% = fileN is that with xargs run the jobs, how to become this output?

How about:
ls -1 | xargs -I% -n1 -P8 bash -c 'echo now run: "$@"; echo myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o "$@".dat "$@"' _ %

Example:
$ touch {1..5}
$ ls -1 | xargs -I% -n1 -P8 bash -c 'echo now run: "$@"; echo myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o "$@".dat "$@"' _ %
now run: 1
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 1.dat 1
now run: 2
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 2.dat 2
now run: 4
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 4.dat 4
now run: 3
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 3.dat 3
now run: 5
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 5.dat 5

You can also drop %:
$ ls -1 | xargs  -n1 -P8 bash -c 'echo now run: "$@"; echo myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o "$@".dat  "$@"' _
now run: 1
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 1.dat 1
now run: 3
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 3.dat 3
now run: 4
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 4.dat 4
now run: 2
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 2.dat 2
now run: 5
myprogramm -s1 -r5 -q -o 5.dat 5

Remove echo before myprogramm to actually run it.
Also remember:
Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?.

you likely never really want to do something like "$@".dat. It works here with just one positional parameter, but if there's e.g. two, it's the same as "$1" "$2".dat. Since this only works with one anyway, using "$1" would make it clearer.

But it's not an issue here providing that fields produced by ls will be split using the default IFS, right?

xargs -n1 will pass just one item to each invocation of the command, yes. (That's what I was trying to say, it works here because of that. It's got nothing to do with IFS, though: xargs splits using its own rules, interpreting quotes too in its own way.) What I mean is the conceptual difference, "$@" being for any number of args, and the surprising effect one gets if they change the surrounding code or copy that elsewhere and pass multiple args to "$@".dat. Using "$1" would make it clearer that the code expects and only works with one arg.

The shell interprets the ; as a command separator even before xargs runs, so it runs xargs and then it runs the echo %.
The argument to xargs is a command to run, not a command list. If you need to run several commands, write them to a script and run it from xargs.
Also, parsing the output of ls is mostly wrong. It doesn't work correctly for filenames containing whitespace.

Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead
